# Unable to display image through PHP in <img> tag

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to display images using the output of a PHP file in a `<img>` tag as I want to process the image with [Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) before displaying it. The following code works fine when I call it in the browser address bar:

**img.php**

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$file = $_GET['image'];

$image = @file_get_contents($file);
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($image);

$im->trimImage(0.1 * \Imagick::getQuantum());
$im->scaleImage(180, 180, true);
echo $im->getImageBlob();
```

But when I use the above code into HTML the image is simply not shown:

```
<img src="img.php?image=http://www.emtshop.it/264024-category_default/tv-led-smart-tech-315-wide-smt32f30hc4u1b1-smart-tv-android-dvb-t2-s2-hd-1366x768-black-ci-slot-3xhdmi-2xusb-vesa.jpg" />
```

Removing the `echo` in the last line does not solve the issue.

**UPDATE**

Browser's developer tools reports Error 404: `www.mysite.com/img.php?image=http://...`  where `www.mysite.com` is my server where I'm running the script (while the image resides on a different server).
But, as asked in my comment below, why it is looking for a file? Shouldn't be the result of a image processing job?

If I call `img.php?image=http://...` directly in the browser's address bar the image is shown correctly.

Comment: For a start, `@` is the error suppression operator. It means: if you couldn't download the file, pretend nothing wrong happened and continue.

Comment: `the image is simply not shown`...so did you look in the browser's Developer Tools to see what happened to the request to img.php when your page was loading? Should be plenty of clues in the Network tool

Comment: Have you checked your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to see what HTTP error you get in the Network tab? Is there any output of the `img.php` url, like an error message?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: @Rob Well it was there in [the XHTML image tag](https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/xhtml/tags-img.html). We don't know what kind of HTML Nicero is trying to write.

Comment: You pointed me to the right way: Error `404`! File not found: `www.mysite.com/img.php?image=http://... ` But I don't understand why it is looking for a file? Should'nt be the result of a image processing job?

Comment: Most likely that the server www.emtshop.it has `allow_url_fopen` **disabled** - which will make file_get_contents FAIL (I suggest you put the image to another server which has allow_url_fopen enabled, retry  and see what happens)

Comment: An image is a file, so if there is no image at the given URL, and nothing else, your web server with respond with a 404 File not found error. Check the image URL carefully.

Comment: Sounds like maybe `www.mysite.com/img.php` isn't the correct URL for your PHP script?